# File name is changed when using allowEdit in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

I am using phonegap to create android application. In that i need to capture the image from **gallery** . So i wrote the following code for capturing image

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(fileEntry){
        fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) { 
        console.log(fileObj.name);
        });
    }, fail);
}, fail, { quality: 100, allowEdit : true,
    targetWidth: 600,
    targetHeight: 600,
    destinationType: destinationType.NATIVE_URI,
    sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY 
});
```

It is working fine and capture the image.

The problem is when insert **allowEdit** in camera options the image name is changed.If i remove the

```
/*allowEdit : true,
        targetWidth: 600,
        targetHeight: 600,*/
```

default image name is persist.

How to **avoid the rename when editing**. Someone help to get out this problem.

Comment: where are you saving your image after edit @Ela

Comment: @Sport saved in my sdcard like appname/files/myimage.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ***phonegap / cordova(version 3.3)*** when using **"allowEdit:true and target height and width"** for camera options the camera plugin has a default name like **"resize.jpg"**.

So it always stored as **resige.jpg** and also it is only for **when pick image from gallery** not when take image using camera .

So you can change the default string in **cameraLauncher.java** (present inside src/org.apache.cordova.camera)

Instead of this

```
// Create an ExifHelper to save the exif data that is lost during compression
 String resizePath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/resize.jpg";
// Some content: URIs do not map to file paths (e.g. picasa).
 String realPath = FileHelper.getRealPath(uri, this.cordova);
```

Replace this

```
String realPath = FileHelper.getRealPath(uri, this.cordova);
int postition = realPath.lastIndexOf( '.' );
// your image format like jpg or png
String imageFormat = realPath.substring(postition+1);
// your image name 
String imageName = realPath.substring(0,postition);
//now the default name is changed 
String resizePath = getTempDirectoryPath() + "/"+imageName+"."+imageFormat;
```

**NOTE *** This answer is only for android