# How to get png pictures with Cordova 3.5 on Android

Tags: android, cordova, camera, png, getpicture

I'm trying to retrieve a PNG picture using cordova-plugin-camera, with that code :

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onPictSuccess, onFailPict, { quality: 50, encodingType:Camera.EncodingType.PNG, destinationType:navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI});
```

But it's always return a JPG file. Did someone succeed getting PNG on Android ?

Looking at tha java plugin source for Android in CameraLauncher.java l.390 and in many other locations ".jpg" seems to be hardcoded :

```
uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(getTempDirectoryPath(), System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg"));
```

I tried replacing ".jpg" with ".png" but of course that only change the name of the extension.

Comment: Does your build of cordova support `encodingType`?

Comment: +1 yes there are some issue with camera plugin another one is like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25800878/file-name-is-changed-when-using-allowedit-in-phonegap/25803398#25803398

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was not so far from the solution. A few lines below in processResultFromCamera() (l.413) a jpeg reference is also hardcoded

```
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, this.mQuality, os);
```

that I replaced by :

```
if (this.encodingType == JPEG) {
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, this.mQuality, os);
}
else if (this.encodingType == PNG) {
     bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, this.mQuality, os);
}
```

So the plugin's doc is wrong PNG isn't supported for Android. And I don't know more about github to correct the code